# pass json parameter as variable to .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

OnbuttonClick trying to Load Page via `.load()` **POST** method. Generated URL parameters and printed as JSON formatted in button attribute `btn-url`.

**Issue:** Parameter is not passed to `.load()` since i'm use javascript variable `page`

***Code:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
                $("#open-content").load($php_self,loadfunctions);
                $("#open-content").on( "click", ".tools a", function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#open-loading-div").show();
                    var page = $(this).attr("btn-url");
                    $("#open-content").load($php_self,page, function(){
                        $("#open-loading-div").hide();
                        loadfunctions();
                    });             
                });         
        });
```

***Working Code:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
                $("#open-content").load($php_self,loadfunctions);
                $("#open-content").on( "click", ".tools a", function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#open-loading-div").show();
                    /*var page = $(this).attr("btn-url");*/
                    $("#open-content").load($php_self,{"pndg":"nta%3d","nm":"umfuiefuzhk%3d","dpt":"sfi%3d}, function(){
                        $("#open-loading-div").hide();
                        loadfunctions();
                    });             
                });         
        });
```

I want the **JSON** stored in `page` variable to be passed as parameter to `.load()`.

**How to pass URL parameters from `page` Variable to `.load()` function?**

Note: `$php_self` and `page` will access **PHP** file via **POST** method

Comment: Can you show us the structure of `page` pls?

Comment: `{"pndg":"nta%3d","nm":"umfuiefuzhk%3d","dpt":"sfi%3d"}` Something like this i'll get when i `alert(page);`

Comment: Is the missing quotation mark a typo?

Comment: Can you add this line: `console.log($.isPlainObject(page));` and give us the result pls?

Comment: yes i missed " in working code

Comment: @Markai i'm getting result as  `false`

Comment: Then, your `page` object is not what you said above. Might it be wrapped in an array or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80367/discussion-between-markai-and-syed-nizamudeen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the `page` object wasn't a `json object`, but a `stringified json object`. However, the `.load` method from `jQuery` accepts strings and plain objects, it does not work with `stringified json`. The simple solution was to change the `.load` call to this:

```
$("#open-content").load($php_self,JSON.parse(page), function(){ 
    $("#open-loading-div").hide(); 
    loadfunctions(); 
});
```